# ActiveRecord Serializer in Rails does not work with newly added associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

I am trying to add an association to an existing model in Rails. These are my two models and my very simple serializer:

```
user.rb
--------
class User < ApplicationRecord
before_create :confirmation_token
  # encrypt password
  # has_secure_password
......
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  
  # Model associations
  has_many :parties, foreign_key: :created_by_id

......


party.rb
------------
class Party < ApplicationRecord
  # model association
  has_many :ticket_categories, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
......


class PartySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  # attributes to be serialized
  attributes :id, :title, :created_by_id, :created_at, :updated_at, .........
  # model association
  has_many :ticket_categories
  belongs_to :user
end




schema.rb
-----------
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_07_20_130631) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

 create_table "parties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    ........
    t.bigint "created_by_id"
    t.index ["created_by_id"], name: "index_parties_on_created_by_id"
  end

  
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.string "email"
  .......
  end



  .....
  add_foreign_key "parties", "users", column: "created_by_id"
end
```

when querying the user via the API, I get the expected party data but for the user: null

and as soon as i want to create a new party via the API, a rollback happens with the error "Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity". As soon as I delete the association belongs_to from the party model, it works as usual again, but I still don't have a working serializer.

The expected result would be:

```
   {
    "id": 78,
    "title": "some title."
    "created_by_id": 9,
    "created_at": "2020-07-20T13:13:44,947Z"
    "updated_at": "2020-07-20T13:13:44,947Z"
    "ticket_categories": [
        {
        ..........
        }
    ],
    "user": {
          // here the user data associated with the party object
             }
}
```

But with the belongs_to in the Model party.rb I get null for user via Postman when using the serializer and even 422 when trying to post a new party:

```
    # POST /parties
  def create
      @party = current_user.parties.create!(party_params)
      current_user.increment!(:partiesCreated, 1)
      json_response(id: @party.id)
  end
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify any options, `belongs_to` will look for a foreign key with the default name – so `belongs_to :user` will look for `user_id`. If, as your code indicates, you want to use `created_by_id` as a foreign key, you need to do `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :created_by_id` (similar to what you've set for `has_many`).

Comment: thank you! I have just noticed the mistake and was about to post the note for others, I just added: foreign_key: :created_by_id